# Import wants to override unchanged fields

Tags: django, django-import-export

If i export to xlsx and reimport, Django-Import-Export reports overwritten fields but there are no changes. I already tried to debug this myself with the skip_row() method but i think im generally doing sommething wrong

**resources.py**

```
class FormatClassResource(resources.ModelResource):
    number = fields.Field(column_name="Nummer", attribute="number")
    barcode = fields.Field(column_name="Barcode", attribute="barcode")
    name = fields.Field(column_name="Name", attribute="name")
    price = fields.Field(column_name="Preis", attribute="price")

    class Meta:
        model = FormatClass
        use_bulk = True
        use_transactions = True
        skip_unchanged = True
        import_id_fields = ["number", "barcode", "name", "price"]
        exclude = ["id"]
```

[Import result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3PIe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some points which may help:

- The import process is going to try to load existing data based on all four attributes in `import_id_fields`
- It will then compare all fields from your Excel file (which correspond to attributes in `FormatClass`) with what is persisted, and if any of them do not match, it will report an 'update'
- Set a breakpoint [here](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/0ad13e0c7267f15f4041b11c5244a8c5b440adf0/import_export/resources.py#L607) to catch which field it thinks has changed.